# Сборка проекта С++/С# из командной строки

Tags: cmd, visual-studio-2015, build

Требуется собрать проект с помощью bat-файла. Параметры сборки следующие:

```
MsVstudio\incredibuilder - тип сборки локальная\распределенная
win32\x64
debug\release
build\rebuild
```

Можно ли как-то при запуске VS передать в неё такие параметры? Читал про команду devenv, она даёт возможность только указать Build или Rebuild.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем локальная сборка делается с помощью MSBuild, как мне посоветовали выше.

Полный пример:

```
msbuild.exe %SolutionPath% /t:build /p:configuration=release /p:platform=x86
```

Запускается из Bat, только после перехода в каталог, в котором находится MSBuild.

Распределённая сборка, через IncrediBuild, делается через BuildConsole:

```
BuildConsole.exe %SolutionPath% /build  /cfg="release|x86"
```

Является командой самой windows cmd, так что ничего придумывать не надо.

Answer (score 4):

Вам нужен MSBuild - это утилита от Майкрософта, которая умеет с командной строки собирать проекты. А вот прикрутить ее в бат файл - это уже простая задача.

Как собрать проект в релизе?

```
MSBuild.exe C:\Folder with Solution\My Solution.sln /property:Configuration=Release
```

как собрать и дебаг, и релиз?

```
MSBuild.exe C:\Folder with Solution\My Solution.sln /property:Configuration=Debug;Release
```

Хочется чего то больше - читаем документацию https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms164311.aspx

P.S. Возможно, придется запускать "VS2015 x86 Native Tools Command Prompt" (ну или под Вашу версию студии) и в его консоли уже выполнять сборку.

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать.

Comment: Спасибо, ваша информация мне помогла.